# ASP.net MVC Login Page Theme/Customisation

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.net mvc to create a login page. However, I would like to know if there are any ASP.net MVC login templates or themes I can implement. I am going for a minimal theme. So something clean. I would appreciate if you could direct me to any sites as I cannot find any help on google.

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to css and html design in general... I would point you toward using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) by twitter.   Here is a [sample login form](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/signin/)

Comment: Ahh ok, so does that mean I would need to manually customise it using CSS?

Comment: You would need to Implement twitter bootstrap for your site design.  That being said, using twitter bootstrap will take care of a whole lot for you if you read up on their [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio comes with  templates, when creating an MVC application select the internet application template.
Here is the description:

> A default ASP.NET MVC 4 project with an account controller that uses
>   forms authentication.

You can tweak it to meet your needs.